# Taskbar + menu doesn't show up

Tags: menu, taskbar

I recently formatted my laptop. When booting, it said

```
ERROR: no such partition / grub rescue
```

I tried to install Ubuntu Netbook, but it gives some errors and the most annoying thing: I can't see the taskbar and the top menu (with Ubuntu logo, hour, mail, etc). Can someone help me with this ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: That's weird. Can you provide some picture?

Answer (score 1):

So, you're talking about two different things:

1. After formatting, the Main Boot Record remains as an OS installation needs to overwrite it.

   Thus, as the MBR is still there but the partition is gone, the GRUB boot loader lets you know that:

   > ERROR: no such partition / grub rescue
2. Can you specify the actual errors? Have you tried hovering or touching the top/bottom?